Analyze number of spreadtab rows for conditionally changing text elements in the document
again I need your help. I'm writing my invoices for my small music busines with LATEX scrlttr2 and with a spreadtab-tables. It is working very well, but I want to have an automatic selection of some sentences depending on the number of rows within the spreadtab. A simple example is:
If there is only one position within the table (so 3 rows: header, position and sum) I want to print sentences with single words (service), if there are more then 3 rows, the plural sentences (services) should be used.
Is it possible to store the number of rows to a counter and then implement a if-then-else-check for selecting the correct phrase? I'm using multicolumn, that's why a hidden column is not working as far as I know.
Please find a code-example here:

\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{marvosym} % for gray color in header
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{xpatch,eurosym}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nprounddigits{2}
\STsetdecimalsep{{,}}
\newcommand{\Eur}{{\,EUR}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% newline
\makeatletter
\def\spreadtab@ii{\IfSubStr\ST@tab{\noexpand\+}{\expandafter\spreadtab@iii\ST@tab\@nil}{}}
\def\spreadtab@iii#1\+#2#3\@nil{\edef\ST@tab{\unexpanded{#1}\unexpanded\expandafter{#2#3}}\spreadtab@ii}%
\xpretocmd\spreadtab@i\spreadtab@ii{}{}
\makeatother

%define a simple command for every invoice-position
\newcommand*\pos[4]{ :={#1} &@ #2 &@ #3 & :={#4}\,\Eur & :={[-4,0]*[-1,0]}\,\Eur\\ \hline}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% fonts
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Latin Modern Sans
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily\color{myblue}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subject}{\mdseries}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small\sffamily\mdseries\color{mygray}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Style
\LoadLetterOption{DIN} %% oder: DINmtext, SN, SNleft, KOMAold.
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{14mm} % Abstand der Signatur von dem closing
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{17mm} % Abstand des Absenderfeldes vom Top
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{275mm} % Abstand des Footers von oben
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\paperwidth}
\@setplength{locwidth}{70mm}   % Breite des Locationfeldes
\@setplength{locvpos}{65mm}    % Abstand des Locationfeldes von oben
\ifdim \useplength{toaddrhpos}>\z@
  \@addtoplength[-2]{firstheadwidth}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\else
  \@addtoplength[2]{firstheadwidth}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\fi
\@setplength{foldmarkhpos}{6.5mm}
\makeatother
\setlength{\textheight}{22cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\footheight}{0mm}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% colour
% define gray for header
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.55}
% define blue for address
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{letter}
{address
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Topic
\setkomavar{subject}{\textbf{Invoice}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\opening{Dear Sir or Madame,}

I would like to invoice you for the following service: %if only one position
% I would like to invoice you for the following services: % if more than one position


\vspace{5pt}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|X|N{5}{2}|N{5}{2}}}
    \hline
@\tiny Amount & @\tiny Unity& @\tiny Description&@ \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\tiny Price per unit} & @\multicolumn{1}{r}{\tiny Sum} \\ \hline
    \+{\pos{1}{h}{abcd}{123.00}}
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{@\textbf{Total}} & :={sum(e1:[0,-1])} \Eur \\ 
\hline
\end{spreadtab}
\ \par
Please transfer the amount to XXX
\par
\closing{XXX}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{letter}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}


Off-topic: marvosym doesn't provide colour in tables or anywhere else. It's a symbols package.

Define a counter. Step it in the definition of \pos. Write the value to the .aux and read it back on the next run. If a document may contain multiple spreadtab environments, what you need to do depends on whether you want the condition to depend on the total number or the number per environment. Please try to minimise your code when posting examples. Your question only requires a few lines of your source.

Off-topic: if you're writing in English, Madam would be the usual honorific, as far as I know.

Thanks for the comments. The original document is in German and contains a lot of packages and definitions. I have tried to shorten the code and translate it quickly for this question.

Something like this?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\nprounddigits{2}
\STsetdecimalsep{{,}}
\newcommand{\Eur}{{\,EUR}}
\makeatletter
\def\spreadtab@ii{\IfSubStr\ST@tab{\noexpand\+}{\expandafter\spreadtab@iii\ST@tab\@nil}{}}
\def\spreadtab@iii#1\+#2#3\@nil{\edef\ST@tab{\unexpanded{#1}\unexpanded\expandafter{#2#3}}\spreadtab@ii}%
\xpretocmd\spreadtab@i\spreadtab@ii{}{}
\makeatother
\newcounter{nopos}
\NewProperty{nopos}{now}{0}{\arabic{nopos}}
\newcommand*\pos[4]{\refstepcounter{nopos} :={#1} &@ #2 &@ #3 & :={#4}\,\Eur & :={[-4,0]*[-1,0]}\,\Eur\\ \hline}
\AddToHook{enddocument}{%
  \RecordProperties{final-nopos}{nopos}
}
\begin{document}
\ifnum\inteval{\RefProperty{final-nopos}{nopos}}>1 services\else service\fi

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|c|X|N{5}{2}|N{5}{2}}}
  \hline
  @\tiny Amount & @\tiny Unity& @\tiny Description&@ \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\tiny Price per unit} & @\multicolumn{1}{r}{\tiny Sum} \\ \hline
  \+{\pos{1}{h}{abcd}{123.00}}
  \+{\pos{1}{h}{abcd}{123.00}}
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{@\textbf{Total}} & :={sum(e1:[0,-1])} \Eur \\ 
  \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}


The vertical EUR(s) in the table is misaligned.

Dear Sebastiano,
I tried to execute your code, but it doesn't work. The command Newproperty is unknown. Is there any package missing? I'm also using scrlttr2 instead of article.

@Mr_Nofreeze Probably your version of LaTeX is too old. \NewProperty is in the kernel. No package necessary.

@Sebastiano I didn't notice that, but you're right. However, I don't think that's my doing ;).

Dear @Sebastiano, Thanks for that hint. Now it is working and also doing, what I want. Problem solved! Thanks a lot!

@Mr_Nofreeze You mean the hint about the EUR(s)?

@Mr_Nofreeze You're welcome. :-)

Dear @cfr, also thanks a lot to you for your help!
Happy to get help from this great community!

Dear Sebastiano and cfr, I now checked your solution in my original document and it is only working as long as I do not use the letter-environment within the document. Do I need to adapt something to get it working within the letter-environment as shown in the example?

I found a solution by my own: Transfering \AddToHook{enddocument}{\RecordProperties{final-nopos}{nopos}} to the letter-environment and changing it to \AtEndEnvironment{letter}{\RecordProperties{final-nopos}{nopos}} made it work!

@Mr_Nofreeze Excellent! I'd have expected it to work written at enddocument, but writing it at the end of the environment will do just as well. (Better, in fact, since it doesn't work otherwise.)
